# Akka http handler json validation

Tags: json, scala, validation, akka, spray-json

I am very new to Scala and Akka. I am trying to write a simple Http handler using akka which receives a json. I would like to marshal this json to a scala class/object for processing. Since it is an input, I would also like to perform basic validation on the required json nodes and the types of values too. I found that I have to use `spray-json` for it. But I am unable to find more information on how to do this, I am looking for samples/templates on this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have a super-simple demo application specifically for your use-case: https://github.com/sap1ens/akka-microservice

You can take a look at Spray serialization/deserialization and Akka integration here: https://github.com/sap1ens/akka-microservice/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/sap1ens/api/Example1Routes.scala

For example, this is the way to use spray-json library:

```
object Example1Routes {
  case class TestAPIObject(thing: String)

  object Example1RoutesProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val testAPIObjectFormat = jsonFormat1(TestAPIObject)
  }
}
```

jsonFormatX takes care about serializers and deserializers for you.

Then you can use it in Spray DSL:

```
entity(as[TestAPIObject]) { request =>
    // ...
}
```

Later you can also see an example of passing messages to Actors from Spray layer using "ask" pattern. More advanced example: http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/